# Можно ли такую схему организовать на OpenCart?

Tags: opencart, интернет-магазин

Есть необходимость организовать несколько региональных магазинов на поддоменах с одной базой данных. Необходимо чтобы База товаров была одна и та же, а в названии товара или категории просто добавлялось к примеру название города:
(название товара) купить в Москве
(название товара) купить в Нижнем Новгороде
(название товара) купить в Казани
Соответственно различаться на сайтах должны страницы с контактами и способами доставки.

Можно ли такую схему организовать на OpenCart?

Answer (score 0):

Можно. В OpenCart можно создавать несколько магазинов на одном движке. Можете почитать об этом [здесь](http://docs.opencart.com/administration/multi-store/)